# Call a word SynonymInfo object variable from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

There might be something fairly simple I am missing here, but I can't quite figure out why I am getting an "Object variable or Object With block not set" error. I am trying to take a string from Excel, and use VBA to call a Word function that yields synonyms. Here is some reproducible simple code that will cause the error I am running into:

```
Public Sub Tester()
    Dim WD As Word.Application
    Dim Syn As Word.SynonymInfo
    Dim wrd As String
    wrd = "Car"
    Set Syn = WD.SynonymInfo(wrd)
End Sub
```

I made sure I went to Tools→References and selected the Microsoft Word Object Library, and I also entered the following code into a Word Application without error:

```
Public Sub Tester()
    Dim Syn As SynonymInfo
    Dim wrd As String
    wrd = "Car"
    Set Syn = SynonymInfo(wrd)
End Sub
```

I am wondering if there is some reference I am not calling? I am trying to replicate from Excel the example seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/synonyminfo-partofspeechlist-property-word) and wondering declaration I am missing from within Excel VBA to call this. Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created your Word Application object so, in your existing code, `WD` is still `Nothing` - therefore you are effectively trying to execute the statement:

```
Set Syn = Nothing.SynonymInfo(wrd)
```

Correct code would be:

```
Public Sub Tester()
    Dim WD As Word.Application
    Dim Syn As Word.SynonymInfo
    Dim wrd As String
    'Create a Word Application object
    Set WD = New Word.Application
    wrd = "Car"
    Set Syn = WD.SynonymInfo(wrd)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was some small step, but for the life of me, couldn't recall what was missing. That worked!

Comment: @DeCodened And, as @AlexP noted, don't forget to include a `WD.Quit` at the end of all your code, or else you will have an instance of Word hanging around clogging up your memory.

Answer (score 0):

You must first `set WD =`*something* before you can say `WD.`*something*.

For example, `set WD = CreateObject ("Word.Application")` (to open a new instance of Word behind the scenes). Don't forget to call `WD.Quit` when the instance of Word is no longer needed.